# MySQL Master-Master Replication Error: "Error Connecting to Master" Error 2003

Tags: centos7, database-replication, mysql-5.7, ubuntu-22.04, master-master

### Context:

I'm migrating a MySQL 5.7.42 database from an existing external (to AWS) CentOS 7 server to a new private subnet Ubuntu 22 AWS EC2. Due to the nature of the surrounding architecture, I require a temporary master-master sync.

The databases are identical (as one is a restored Percona XtraBackup of the other), bar their server id and id offset. The only noticeable difference is their base OS.

Both servers communicate over a single outbound reverse port-mapped SSH connection from the EC2 through a Bastion. The SSH config maps outbound connections hitting port 3307 over the tunnel from either server to the recipient's port 3306.

**Replication with CentOS as primary and Ubuntu as secondary works.**

### Problem:

**BUT Replication with Ubuntu as primary and CentOS as secondary fails**, resulting in this CentOS `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` output:

```
Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
error connecting to master 'replicatorEC2@127.0.0.1:3307' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1
```

There is no denied connection log on the Ubuntu machine, and the error log on CentOS is as follows:

```
[ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'replicatorEC2@127.0.0.1:3307' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1, Error_code: 2003
```

**This suggests that the CentOS replication process isn't hitting the Ubuntu server.**

### How I got here tl;dr:

I've created a mock version of the architecture so I can blow stuff up without worrying.

I've created a mock database on CentOS and cloned it via Percona XtraBackup 2.4 to Ubuntu.

I've created a replication user on each database and granted them `REPLICATION SLAVE`.

I've then set up the `CHANGE MASTER TO` command on each machine to point at the other.

### What does work:

Each server is accessible from the other at `127.0.0.1:3307` via the MySQL CLI over the ssh tunnel.

The replication users can log in and have the appropriate grant.

The master.info file is appropriately populated by `CHANGE MASTER TO`.

### Notes:

There is no meaningful diff in `SHOW VARIABLES;` output between the database servers

The my.cnf file is identical (except for server id and id autoincrement offset)

The master.info file is identical (except for binlog details AND as CentOS has never managed to connect as a secondary server, it hasn't got a recorded server uuid in there)

The replication users are identical except for the username.

**Moved the troubleshooting section to the end, as it continues to grow.**

### How I got here in detail:

**CentOS**

Created a new CentOS 7 server using iptables as the firewall with the following rules:

```
sudo iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target  prot source    destination
ACCEPT  all  anywhere  anywhere    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT  all  anywhere  anywhere
LOG     tcp  anywhere  anywhere    tcp dpt:SSHPort recent: UPDATE seconds: 10 hit_count: 5 name: SSH side: source mask: 255.255.255.255 LOG level debug prefix "SSH Repeat Attempts"

DROP    tcp  anywhere  anywhere    tcp dpt:SSHPort recent: UPDATE seconds: 10 hit_count: 6 name: SSH side: source mask: 255.255.255.255

ACCEPT  tcp  anywhere  anywhere    tcp dpt:SSHPort recent: SET name: SSH side: source mask: 255.255.255.255

ACCEPT  icmp anywhere  anywhere    icmp echo-request
LOGGING all  anywhere  anywhere
ACCEPT  tcp  anywhere  anywhere    tcp dpt:opsession-prxy
ACCEPT  tcp  anywhere  anywhere    tcp dpt:mysql

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target  prot source    destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target  prot source    destination

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
target  prot source    destination
LOG     all  anywhere  anywhere    limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "

DROP    all  anywhere  anywhere
```

Installed MySQL 5.7.42:

```
// Install wget
sudo yum install wget

// Get the MySQL community release
sudo yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm

// Fix gpg key mismatch
sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022

// Install mysql community server
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

Start service

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Get the default server password

```
sudo grep 'password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Setup MySQL

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
// Enable password validation
// Disable anonymous users
// Disable remote root
// Remove test database
// Reload privilege table
```

Update MySQL config:

```
[mysqld]
bind_address =              *

datadir =                   /var/lib/mysql
socket =                    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

server-id =                 # a unique id
auto_increment_increment =  2
auto_increment_offset =     1 # this is 2 on the Ubuntu server

log_bin =                   /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog-ignore-db =          mysql

relay-log =                 /var/lib/mysql/relay-bin
relay-log-index =           /var/lib/mysql/relay-bin.index
relay-log-info-file =       /var/lib/mysql/relay-bin.info

log-error =                 /var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file =                  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links =            0
```

Create mockDB:

```
mysql -u root -p

CREATE DATABASE mockDB;

USE mockDB;

CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    age INT
);

INSERT INTO customers (name, email, age)
VALUES ('John Doe', 'john.doe@example.com', 30);
```

Create a user to handle the backup process

```
CREATE USER 'replicatorCentOS'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replicatorCentOS'@'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Record binlog position

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

Example SHOW MASTER STATUS; response

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000002 |     2142 |              | mysql            |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Install Percona XtraBackup 2.4

```
sudo yum install https://repo.percona.com/yum/percona-release-latest.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install percona-xtrabackup-24
```

Create a hot backup with Percona XtraBackup

```
sudo xtrabackup --backup --no-timestamp --user=root --password='password' --target-dir=/home/user/backup
```

Permissions for backup files

```
sudo chown -R user:group ~/backup
sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/backup
```

Compress the backup

```
tar -cpzvf backup.tar.gz -C ~/backup .
```

Install AWS CLI

```
sudo yum install awscli
```

Configure AWS CLI

```
aws configure
```

Upload the compressed backup to S3

```
aws s3 cp backup.tar.gz s3://s3Address/backup.tar.gz
```

**Ubuntu**

AWS infrastructure:

- I created a new Ubuntu 22 EC2 on a private subnet.
- The private subnet has a NAT gateway.
- The AZ (Availability Zone) containing the private subnet also has a public subnet.
- The public subnet contains a Bastion EC2 that connects to the private subnet's NAT gateway.
- The public subnet contains an IGW (Internet Gateway) that connects it to the internet.
- The security groups allow outbound SSH connections.
- The EC2 uses UFW as its firewall, but has no rules, relying on security groups/bastion.

SSH config

```
Host centOSReverse
  HostName centOSPublicIP
  Port SSH port
  User user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/sshKey
  ProxyJump bastion
  LocalForward 3307 localhost:3306
  RemoteForward 3307 localhost:3306

Host bastion
  HostName bastionPrivateIP
  Port SSH port
  User user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/sshKey

Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60
  ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

Reverse port map ssh from Ubuntu ssh to CentOS.

```
ssh -f -N centOSReverse
autossh -M -f -N centOSReverse
```

Close the connections like this:

```
pkill -f "ssh -f -N centOSReverse"
pkill -f "autossh -M -f -N centOSReverse"
```

Install MySQL 5.7.42

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb
// Select Bionic and hit OK
// Select the first option
// Select MySQL 5.7
// Select OK

// Add the MySQL APT repository key
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29

sudo apt-get update

// Install MySQL 5.7
sudo apt install -f mysql-client=5.7* mysql-community-server=5.7* mysql-server=5.7*
```

Install Percona XtraBackup 2.4

```
wget https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_latest.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i percona-release_latest.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install percona-xtrabackup-24
```

Install/configure AWS CLI

```
sudo apt-get install awscli
aws configure
```

Download backup

```
aws s3 cp s3://S3Address/backup.tar.gz ~/backup.tar.gz
```

Uncompress backup

```
mkdir backup
tar -xpzvf ~/backup.tar.gz -C ~/backup
```

Prepare backup

```
xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/home/user/backup
```

Stop MySQL service

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Clear MySQL datadir

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Restore backup

```
sudo xtrabackup --copy-back --target-dir=/home/user/backup
```

Adjust permissions

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo find /var/lib/mysql -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
sudo find /var/lib/mysql -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

Start MySQL service

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Create a user to handle the backup process

```
CREATE USER 'replicatorUbuntu'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replicatorUbuntu'@'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Record binlog position

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

Example SHOW MASTER STATUS; response

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |      953 |              | mysql            |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Both servers**

Run change master to script

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter the replication master username: " username
read -s -p "Enter the replication master password: " password
echo ""
read -p "Enter the replication host: " host
read -p "Enter the replication port: " port
read -p "Enter the log file name: " logFile
read -p "Enter the log position: " logPosition
echo "MySQL root password below: "
mysql -u root -p -e "
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='$host', MASTER_PORT=$port, MASTER_USER='$username', MASTER_PASSWORD='$password', MASTER_LOG_FILE='$logFile', MASTER_LOG_POS=$logPosition;
START SLAVE;"
```

Make executable

```
chmod +x mysql_replication.sh
```

Run

- If we are logging into:

  - `replicatorCentOS` from Ubuntu, we want to use the binlog data from CentOS
  - `replicatorUbuntu` from CentOS, we want to use the binlog data from Ubuntu

Example responses
CentOS

```
./mysql_replication.sh
username: replicatorUbuntu
replicatorUbuntuPassword
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 3307
logFile: mysql-bin.000002
LogPosition: 2142
MySQLRootPassword
```

Ubuntu

```
./mysql_replication.sh
username: replicatorCentOS
replicatorCentOSPassword
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 3307
logFile: mysql-bin.000002
LogPosition: 2142
MySQLRootPassword
```

And voila, you will have half of the intended replication working for some reason.

### My current theory:

All I know is that the problem is between the CentOS MySQL server and ends before it leaves the CentOS server.

### Troubleshooting:

I've blown away and rebuilt these servers a few times now.
Some things are too permissive in my desperation to fix this; I'll tighten them up once it's working.

**Enabled general and verbose logging via MySQL config**

```
log_error_verbosity =       3
general_log =               ON
general_log_file =          /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

**MySQL documentation:**
Many posts suggest reading a dead MySQL docs page for Access Denied
I believe these to be its analogues for 5.7:

- [6.2 Access Control and Account Management](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/access-control.html) for a general overview
- [6.2.17 Troubleshooting Problems Connecting to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html) for specifics

Going to run debugging soon
[Debugging and creating trace files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/dbug-package.html).
[Debugging options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_debug).

Research:
**[Remove bind-address from config](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194680/setting-up-master-slave-replication-error-connecting-to-master-error-code-)**

- Tried both removing and setting to permissive, same null result

**Many `error 2003` questions are resolved with firewall changes:**

- Disabling the firewall on the CentOS had no effect
- Given everything is in and otherwise working over the SSH tunnel that makes sense):

Disable iptables firewall

```
sudo systemctl stop iptables
sudo systemctl status iptables
```

Reset replication process:

```
mysql -u root -p
STOP SLAVE;
START SLAVE;

SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

Slave status error

```
Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replicatorUbuntu@127.0.0.1:3307' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1
```

Check error log

```
sudo tail -n 100 /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Logged error

```
[ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'replicatorUbuntu@127.0.0.1:3307' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1, Error_code: 2003
```

Restart iptables service

```
sudo systemctl start iptables
sudo systemctl status iptables
```

**Verify SSH connection**
I tried an outbound SSH connection from each server in case there was something about the reverse port map, but I got the same result:

Test Ubuntu SSH config:

```
Host CentOS
  HostName CentOSPublicIP
  Port SSHPort
  User User
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/SSHKey
  ProxyJump bastion
  LocalForward 3307 localhost:3306

Host bastion
  HostName BastionLocalIP
  Port SSHPort
  User User
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/SSHKey

Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60
  ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

Test CentOS SSH config:

```
Host Ubuntu
  HostName UbuntuLocalIP
  Port SSHPort
  User User
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/SSHKey
  ProxyJump bastion
  LocalForward 3307 localhost:3306

Host bastion
  HostName BastionPublicIP
  Port SSHPort
  User User
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/SSHKey

Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60
  ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

**[SELinux](https://serverfault.com/questions/461704/mysql-error-2003-over-ssh-tunnel-when-replicating-not-when-using-client) on the CentOS server:**
Check if SELinux is enabled and in it's default 'enforcing' mode

- Meaning it will block any port not defined in its port list

```
sestatus
```

- It is

Check existing port rules

```
sudo semanage port -l
```

- 3307 isn't on there

According to the thread this should tell SELinux to allow mysql to connect through port 3307

```
semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 3307
```

**THAT WAS IT!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding port 3307 to SELinux solved it:

```
semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 3307
```

My problem was a duplicate of this: https://serverfault.com/questions/461704/mysql-error-2003-over-ssh-tunnel-when-replicating-not-when-using-client

My first time setting up a CentOS server so I didn't know it would be on and blocking any ports without explicit rules.